# ACL truncates action name

Tags: mysql, acl, phalcon

Using [PhalconPHP framework](https://phalconphp.com/en/)

I have been using ACL successfully for a while but ran into an issue when I tried using an action name that was more than 16 characters long. When I add `adminChangePassword` as an access under my `users` resource | get the error

```
Access 'adminChangePassw' does not exist in resource 'users'
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory->_allowOrDeny('Administrators', 'users', 'adminChangePass...', 1)
```

But using the name `adminChangePassw` works fine (apart from that it is a rubbish name). It appears that the name is being truncated at some point which I presume would be a bug.

Is that what is happening or can anyone give another explanation of this error?

**A quick test**

I've just tried adding an access in the `users` resource called `12345678901234567` and the error says that `1234567890123456` does not exist - truncating the last `7`...

**Occurs in tutorial programs**

I tried adding 'adminChangePassword' to the ACL in my working [Vokuro](https://vokuro.phalconphp.com/) example and get the same error - so it isn't related to any changes I have made to how the ACL works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because I had been working from the Vokuro example code - the database for which limits the size of the action and resource fields to 16 characters. Changing the database setup to allow more characters in those fields fixes the problem.

Comment: interesting lesson. Thanks!